# How to create WPF listBox template

Tags: .net, listbox, itemssource

I've got an application, which uses many listBoxes with data attached to them using listBox.ItemsSource. The problem is it creates entries like [namespace].[class_name].

How can I create a template, which will replace entries with, eg. class "Name" field?

I look forward to hear from you soon,
MattheW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[namespace].[classname] is the default implementation of the `ToString` method, which is called if you don't specify what to display.

You can use the `DisplayMemberPath` property to specify which member of the class you want to display :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

If you want more control on how the items are displayed, you can define a `DataTemplate` for your data type and assign it to the `ItemTemplate` property of the `ListBox`

Answer (score 0):

A good example of ListBox implementation is here

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/534/